# error in json decode - Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, json

I have this piece of code:-

```
<?php 
$xml = file_get_contents("http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20url,%20normalized_url,%20share_count,%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20total_count,%20commentsbox_count,%20comments_fbid,%20click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url='http://www.facebook.com/nokia'");
echo $xml;
$obj = json_decode($xml);
print $obj;
print $obj->{'like_count'};
?>
```

And it gives me the following error:-

```
{"data":[{"url":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/nokia","normalized_url":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/nokia","share_count":1240,"like_count":8622663,"comment_count":287,"total_count":8624190,"commentsbox_count":2,"comments_fbid":404897301238,"click_count":10}]}
Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\nokia_app\test.php on line 5
```

How i can rectify it?

Comment: @andrewsi Then how i would be able to fetch the data in json? otherwise also, its giving me this error after commenting `Notice: Undefined variable: obj in C:\xampp\htdocs\nokia_app\test.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined variable: obj in C:\xampp\htdocs\nokia_app\test.php on line 6

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\nokia_app\test.php on line 6`

Comment: From the look of the error message, you're trying to print out `$obj`, but PHP can't directly print it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to study what API returns before asking these type of questions.

```
$xml = file_get_contents("http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20url,%20normalized_url,%20share_count,%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20total_count,%20commentsbox_count,%20comments_fbid,%20click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url='http://www.facebook.com/nokia'");
$obj = json_decode($xml);
var_dump($obj->data[0]->{'like_count'});
```

Comment: ok that's what i was looking for. But the output is `int(1522)` how i can just get the `1522` as answer. Is there something that can be done, or php str_replace has to be used?

Comment: `echo $obj->data[0]->{'like_count'}`

Comment: I do agree with you, was new to such things. Thanks for all your help @Tim

Comment: @BaylorRae' ok, i got the point. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to work with data in an array try this:

```
class ObjectToArray {
    public static function convert( $object ) {
    if( !is_object( $object ) && !is_array( $object ) ) {
        return $object;
    }

    if( is_object( $object ) ) {
        $object = get_object_vars( $object );
    }

    return array_map( 'ObjectToArray::convert', $object );
     }
}

$aData = ObjectToArray::format($theObject);

print_r($aData);
```